# angular2 *ngIf doesnt work when true and array is empty

Tags: angular, typescript

so I have this code :

this is the templateUrl:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="showNewPop()" >New</button>{{shownew}}
<app-new-pop *ngIf="shownew"  (close)="closeNewPop($event)"></app-new-pop>
```

and this is the Component.ts

```
 private shownew = false;
 private myBooksArr:Book[];

 constructor(private bookService:BookService) { 
   this.myBooksArr = Array<Book>();
 }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getBooks();  
 }

 showNewPop(){
   this.shownew = true;
 }

 closeNewPop(newBook:Book){
   this.shownew = false;
   if (newBook) {
     this.myBooksArr.splice(0, 0, newBook);
   }
 }

 private getBooks(){
   this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(data=>{
     data.items.forEach(element => {
       this.myBooksArr.push(new Book(element.id,
                                     element.volumeInfo.authors,
                                     element.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
                                     element.volumeInfo.title));
     });
   });
 }
```

now the problem is that when ever the myBooksArr array is empty 
shownew becomes true but the *ngIf does not show the app-new-pop Component

and i can't figure out why

this is the delete book function if it helps

```
 showDeletePop(i:number) {
   this.currnetBook = this.myBooksArr[i];
   this.currnetBook.indedx = i;
   this.showDelete = true;
 }

 closeDeleetePop(mydelete:boolean){
   this.showDelete = false;
   if(mydelete){
     this.myBooksArr.splice(this.currnetBook.indedx,1);
   }
 }
```

**Update!!**

found a **hack** that works if any one is interested. 
this is it :

```
 private flag:boolean= false;
 showNewPop(){
   console.log(this.myBooksArr.length);
   if(this.myBooksArr.length==0){
     this.myBooksArr.push(new Book("",[""],"0",""))
     this.flag =true;
   }
   this.shownew = true;
 }

 closeNewPop(newBook:Book){
   this.shownew = false;
   if(newBook && !this.flag){
     this.myBooksArr.splice(0, 0, newBook);
   }
   if(newBook && this.flag){
     this.myBooksArr.splice(0,1,newBook);
     this.flag = false;
   }
 }
```

I still would like to know why didn't it work in the first place tho
if you know it would be cool

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the *ngIf in a div.

```
<div *ngIf="shownew">
<app-new-pop (close)="closeNewPop($event)"></app-new-pop>
</div>
```

In the reference to ngIf: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-if-simple',
  template: `
    <button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
    show = {{show}}
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="show">Text to show</div>
`
})
class NgIfSimple {
  show: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: you should be able to use [hidden]="!shownew" attribute binding.

Comment: I tried this 
it doesn't work
I still have the same problem

Comment: @AdiGoldner can you try without the (close) ="closeNewPop($event)".

Comment: @AdiGoldner Does app-new-pop contain an attribute "close"?

Comment: I need the close event it is an @output() function from the NewPopComponent
that sends a new book created in the newPop form to the parent component
which than saves it

Comment: @AdiGoldner Ohhh 
Have you looked at this? 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you mising a `}` before `ngOnInit` ?

```
constructor(private bookService:BookService) { 
  this.myBooksArr = Array<Book>();
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.getBooks();  
}
```